# Return query result with union inside query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have 3 tables in database like this

Table `availability`

```
availability_id | date       | price | room_id | closed
-------------------------------------------------------
        1       | 2017-01-24 |   75  |  8      | 0
        2       | 2017-01-24 |   95  |  9      | 0
        3       | 2017-01-25 |   80  | 73      | 0
        4       | 2017-01-25 |   70  | 65      | 0
        5       | 2017-01-26 |   85  | 42      | 0
        6       | 2017-01-26 |   65  | 21      | 0
```

Table `offer_day`

```
plan_id | offer_id date | price      | room_id |    | closed 
------------------------------------------------------------
 1      |       12      | 2017-01-24 |   70    |  8 |   0
 2      |       23      | 2017-01-24 |   75    |  9 |   0
 3      |       12      | 2017-01-25 |   70    |  8 |   1
 3      |       14      | 2017-01-25 |   70    |  8 |   0
 4      |       34      | 2017-01-25 |   75    |  9 |   0
 5      |       43      | 2017-01-25 |   80    | 73 |   0   
 6      |       54      | 2017-01-25 |   85    | 65 |   0 
 7      |       65      | 2017-01-26 |   75    | 42 |   0
 8      |       44      | 2017-01-26 |   70    | 21 |   0
```

Table `package_day`

```
package_id | date       | price | room_id | closed
--------------------------------------------------
    1      | 2017-01-24 |  120  |   8     | 0
    2      | 2017-01-24 |  125  |   9     |  0
    3      | 2017-01-25 |  135  |  73     | 0
    4      | 2017-01-25 |  130  |  65     | 0
    5      | 2017-01-26 |  125  |  42     | 0 
    5      | 2017-01-26 |  120  |  21     | 0
```

I have query like this :

```
SELECT a.price 
FROM availability a
WHERE a.closed = 0 AND a.date >= '2017-01-24' AND a.date <= DATE_SUB('2017-01-26', INTERVAL 1 DAY)

UNION

SELECT 0.price 
FROM offer_day o
WHERE o.closed = 0 AND o.date >= '2017-01-24' AND o.date <= DATE_SUB('2017-01-26', INTERVAL 1 DAY)

UNION

SELECT p.price 
FROM package_day p
WHERE p.closed = 0 AND p.date >= '2017-01-24' AND p.date <= DATE_SUB('2017-01-26', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

If I run that query I will get all the rows that `closed = 0`. As you can see in the table `offer_day` there is value 1 in column `closed`.

I don't want to show the result if any rows in column `close` in same `room_id` and same `offer_id` contain value 1.

Example, you can see in table `offer_day` that `room_id` 8 has two dates '2017-01-24' and '2017-01-25' and two `offer_id` 12 and 14 that in date '2017-01-25' has 1 in `closed` and in `offer_id` 8. I dont want to show that `room_id` 8 and `offer_id` 12 if any rows contain value 1

How can I do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: you have a condition -> x.closed = 0 , with this in your query you will get all the records that have closed=0

Comment: ya I know that. But, I want that in date range that I input if there is value 1 in coloumn closed I dont want to show all the records @RafaelShkembi

Comment: What's the problem with your query? What's the output? What output are you expecting?

Comment: I don't want to show all the records if there is value 1 in coloumn closed. @shmosel

Comment: None of them? You want an empty result set?

Comment: yes I want empty result @shmosel

Comment: Any column? Surely any row !?!?!?!?

Comment: ya I mean in any row in coloumn closed @Strawberry

Comment: If only there was an edit button

Comment: there is no edit button @Strawberry that query I was used for show room and hotel rates.

Comment: may be you can use            where **your condition**   and  case when o.closed = 1 AND o.date >= '2017-01-24' AND o.date <= DATE_SUB('2017-01-26', INTERVAL 1 DAY) then 1=2 end

Comment: can you give me some example to write that ? @krishnpatel

Comment: SELECT o.price 
FROM offer_day o
WHERE o.closed = 0 AND o.date >= '2017-01-24' AND o.date <= DATE_SUB('2017-01-26', INTERVAL 1 DAY) and  case when o.closed = 1 AND o.date >= '2017-01-24' AND o.date <= DATE_SUB('2017-01-26', INTERVAL 1 DAY) then 1=2 end

Comment: run it and tell me it's result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do not want room you can use bleow query

```
SELECT a.price 
FROM availability a
WHERE a.closed = 0 AND a.date >= '2017-01-24' AND a.date <= DATE_SUB('2017-01-26', INTERVAL 1 DAY) and a.room_id NOT IN (select room_id FROM availability WHERE closed = 1 AND date >= '2017-01-24' AND date <= '2017-01-26')

UNION

SELECT o.price 
FROM offer_day o
WHERE o.closed = 0 AND o.date >= '2017-01-24' AND o.date <= DATE_SUB('2017-01-26', INTERVAL 1 DAY) and o.room_id NOT IN (select room_id FROM offer_day WHERE closed = 1 AND date >= '2017-01-24' AND date <= '2017-01-26')

UNION

SELECT p.price 
FROM package_day p
WHERE p.closed = 0 AND p.date >= '2017-01-24' AND p.date <= DATE_SUB('2017-01-26', INTERVAL 1 DAY) and p.room_id NOT IN (select room_id FROM package_day WHERE closed = 1 AND date >= '2017-01-24' AND date <= '2017-01-26')
```

you can see if closed=1  i get it's room id and use it not in room id.
now have you got your ans ?

Comment: I just change coloumn offer_id to plan_id and add offer_id as new coloumn. Please look again into my questions.

Comment: i have given idea now you can make new query your own way

Answer (score 0):

You asked in the comments that if a closed record is 1 then you don't want to take any records from your table. You can make a subquery to check if you have any values you dont want.
Here is an example

```
SELECT a.price 
FROM availability a
WHERE a.closed = 0 AND a.date >= '2017-01-24' AND a.date <= DATE_SUB('2017-01-26', INTERVAL 1 DAY) and a.closed NOT IN (select closed FROM availability WHERE closed = 1 AND date >= '2017-01-24' AND date <= '2017-01-26')

UNION

SELECT o.price 
FROM offer_day o
WHERE o.closed = 0 AND o.date >= '2017-01-24' AND o.date <= DATE_SUB('2017-01-26', INTERVAL 1 DAY) and o.closed NOT IN (select closed FROM offer_day WHERE closed = 1 AND date >= '2017-01-24' AND date <= '2017-01-26')

UNION

SELECT p.price 
FROM package_day p
WHERE p.closed = 0 AND p.date >= '2017-01-24' AND p.date <= DATE_SUB('2017-01-26', INTERVAL 1 DAY) and p.closed NOT IN (select closed FROM package_day WHERE closed = 1 AND date >= '2017-01-24' AND date <= '2017-01-26')
```

Comment: may be it will not work if there is any data o.closed =1 then do not bring any single data event o.closed =0 other value in given data range

Comment: @krishnpatel yes i know but the OP asked said that he want to take all the records with closed=0 but if a record with closed=1 exists in table don't take any results. i have forgoten the date filter in the subquery i will update my answer

Comment: @Antonio now i get it. Please wait a couple of minutes i will update my ansewer

Comment: @RafaelShkembi can you update your ans now he want room wise

Comment: Are you finish with your answer ?